# Unable to start activity NullPointerException TextView.setText

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have a problem with my android application. I tried another solution from StackOverflow, but with no result. Now, I really don't know, where I have a mistake. I know, that variable info is empty, but I don't know why, because it is defined in `activity_dashboard.xml` and AndroidStudio whispered me that id.

**Error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: cz.revelio.mhdapp, PID: 16181
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cz.revelio.mhdapp/cz.revelio.mhdapp.DashboardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at cz.revelio.mhdapp.DashboardActivity.onCreate(DashboardActivity.java:27)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

DashboardActivity.java

```
package cz.revelio.mhdapp;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.List;

public class DashboardActivity extends BaseActivity{
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    TextView info;
    Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    int vsechyZaznamy = mDatabaseHelper.getCountAllLogs();
    int unikatniZaznamy = mDatabaseHelper.getCountUniqueLogs();
    info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info_count_in_dash);
    info.setText(vsechyZaznamy+" záznamů, z toho "+unikatniZaznamy+" unikátních.");
    recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    getData();
}
public void getData(){
    List<String> dataZaznamy = mDatabaseHelper.getAllLogs();
    String[] zaznamy = new String[dataZaznamy.size()];
    zaznamy = dataZaznamy.toArray(zaznamy);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new Adapter(this,zaznamy));
}

}
```

BaseActivity.java

```
    package cz.revelio.mhdapp;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.base, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DashboardActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Zatím není k dispozici", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Zatím není k dispozici", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Zatím není k dispozici", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send2) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Zatím není k dispozici", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
    }
}
```

activity_dashboard.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="cz.revelio.mhdapp.DashboardActivity">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_count_in_dash"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:itemCount="5"
        tools:listitem="@layout/costume_row" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Did you forget to call `setContentView` in your `DashboardActivity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its gonna work like that. You are not setting the content view in the Dashboard activity. That's why it cant find the textview and it comes out to be null. When the activity starts, it will call the onCreate of DashboardActivity and not that of BaseActivity.

If you are thinking that since you have created the content in the base class's onCreate, then it will automatically do it for the subclasses, then you are wrong.